# How to extract words between two characters in linux?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have the following stored in a file named tmp.txt

```
user/config/jars/content-config-factory-3.2.0.0.jar
```

I need to store this word to a variable -

```
$variable=content-config-factory
```

I have written the following

```
  while read line
   do
    var=$(echo $line | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\/"; OFS=" "} {print $NF}' )
    var=$(echo $var | awk 'BEGIN{FS="-"; OFS=" "} {print $(1)}' )
    echo $var
  done < tmp.txt
```

This returns the result "content" instead of "content-config-factory".

Can anyone please tell me how to extract a word between two characters from a string efficiently.

Comment: what could be the other kind of content (always a Path/some word separate by `-` than a series of numer separate by dot and the final word ? because for your question it is simpler to  write `variable=content-config-factory` assuming content doesn't change

Answer (score 4):

An `awk` solution would be like

```
awk -F/ '{sub("-[^-]+$", "", $NF); print $NF}
```

**Test**

```
$ echo "user/config/jars/content-config-factory-3.2.0.0.jar" | awk -F/ '{sub("-[^-]+$", "", $NF); print $NF}'
content-config-factory
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way also and get your expected result

```
 variable=$(sed 's:.*/\(.*\)-.*:\1:'  FileName)

 echo $variable
```

**OutPut :**

```
content-config-factory
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use grep,

```
grep -oP '(?<=/)[^/]*(?=-\d+\.)' file
```

Example:

```
$ var=$(echo 'user/config/jars/content-config-factory-3.2.0.0.jar' | grep -oP '(?<=/)[^/]*(?=-\d+\.)')
$ echo "$var"
content-config-factory
```